# Issues with C# HttpClient Timeout

Tags: c#, httprequest

I'm making a simple GetAsync() request with an HttpClient object. When I retrieve a small amount of data this way, the request works fine. When I try to retrieve a large amount of data the request times out.

I tried to set the HttpClient's Timeout property to 5 minutes like so:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
```

before making the call, but it still times out after ~60 seconds.

I've read in several answers to use HttpWebRequest to access more granular timeout options, but I'm using .net 4.5.2 and references to HttpWebRequest won't compile.

How can I increase the readwrite timeout of the HttpClient?

Comment: [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest` has been in the framework since 1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: What kind of application is this (console, asp.net, etc.)? Is the other end killing the connection?

Comment: HttpClient is more recent then WebRequest (of course). A timeout may be generated by the source.

Comment: Have you checked if the problem still persists if you query a different server? I mean could it be that the timeout is enforced from the server side?

Comment: @stuartd well, it doesn't seem to be usable after 4.5.

Comment: @Jasen console application. Don't think it's the source killing it. I run the same request through the APIs test webpage and it returns data ok.

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem I know [for a fact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.5.2) it exists and is "usable" in 4.5.2 and beyond

Comment: *it doesn't seem to be usable after 4.5*. Where did you get this from? It's perfectly working. Instead, post you HttpClient setup (headers included).

Comment: Ah, apparently you can't just do "var req = new HttpWebRequest();" Casting it from WebRequest.Create() seems to work though.

Comment: There's also [WebRequest.CreateHttp()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.createhttp(v=vs.110).aspx) that does not need a cast. You'll find working examples on WebRequest all over SO and MSDN.